# How can I unwrap Guice ProvisionException?

Tags: java, exception, dependency-injection, guice

In case and exception is thrown while Guice is creating a class a 
`ProvisionException` wraps the original exception.

Is there a way to force the throw of the original exception instead?

For instance:

```
@Inject
public myClass() {

  throw new MySpecificException();
}
```

I know, I can catch `ProvisionException` and call `getCause()` to unwrap and get to the `MySpecificException`. However, if possible I would prefer to override the default Guice exception instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, you can't.

`ProvisionException` does a lot more than wrap one Exception; Guice is set up to catch many exceptions at once, roll them together into a single Exception and send a convenient, useful message back to you to figure out what went wrong.

For example, in the Guice source code there's lots of [code like this](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java#L114):

```
try {
  result = callable.call();
  // Make sure we don't return the provisioned object if there were any errors
  // injecting its field/method dependencies.
  errors.throwIfNewErrors(numErrorsBefore);
} catch(ErrorsException ee) {
  exceptionDuringProvision = ee;
  throw new ProvisionException(errors.merge(ee.getErrors()).getMessages())
}
```

The error handling system is so deeply integrated that you're not going to be able to extract it out; and, honestly, why would you want to? The whole point of doing it this way is to make it easy for you to isolate the problem. If you're getting a `ProvisionException`, that means that **your code is doing the wrong thing and needs to be changed**; it is not the sort of thing that you can recover from and return to normal operations.

In my production system, I catch many exceptions in various places and handle them, log them and attempt to recover. But, `ProvisionException` is not one of them; if my system throws it, I want the whole darn thing to crash so I can figure it out immediately and fix it. (Of course, by the time I'm deploying a new build, it's been thoroughly tested so that I know, at the very least, if there is a problem it's not going to be `ProvisionException`).

Comment: Constructors can throw errors due to transient errors, and one should be able to recover in those instances, without restarting the entire application. Guice design is really opinionated in this matter, which makes it harder to use.